# angular $localStorage is not working on WP8

Tags: angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am using https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage in my Cordova Project with AngularJS framwork. $localStorage works fine on Android and iPhone but it is not working on WP8. When try to use $localStorage another controller the data is not persist. can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider using angular storage
https://github.com/auth0/angular-storage

instead of $localstorage hope it will work

Thanks